# What's Android Equivalent of iOS's Post Notification and Delegate function?

Tags: iphone, android

I find the Post notification and delegate function are very useful in iOS. Once I finish a task I can notify another piece of code to do something. I am sending out notices for others to do the work.

Post Notification is when you sending notice right away, whereas delegate sometime down the line it will send a notice.

In Android I know there's event Listener, but that's only passive listening. What about me actively sending notices? Does Android have that equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) which can be fired right away or with [postDelay()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) you can fire them later

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to get notified from a running Thread or the [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which does run some code and after it's finished it notifies the UI Thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for a way to thread your application? Where there are other "worker" threads that do long computations (or do buffered IO stuff). The way you would do this is by creating an AsyncTask. Within an AsyncTask, there is a "doInBackground" method that seems to be what "delegate" is in your question. "onPostExecute" will handle whatever's returned in "doInBackground". More in the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Another option is to simply use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and use postDelay() for later executions: